# Why do I keep getting an index error when trying to delete, when replacing with a character works fine?

Tags: python, rosalind

Programming newb/python newb, my job is super undemanding so I've found a lot of free time to teach myself how to code.

I'm working [this](http://rosalind.info/problems/prot/) rosalind.info problem.

Here is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jan 21 09:01:51 2016

@author: aseyedian
"""
codon = ''

q=0
with open('rosalind_prot.txt', 'r') as prot:
    bb = list(prot.read())

mylist = []   
for i in range(len(bb)):
     mylist.append(bb[i])


for i in range(0, len(bb),3):
    mylist[i] = [''.join(mylist[i:i+3])]

for i in range(1, len(mylist), 3):
    del mylist[i]

for i in range(2, len(mylist), 3):
    del mylist[i]

print mylist
#This is to create a list of codons which then are translated into amino acids
```

for some reason,

```
for i in range(1, len(mylist), 3):
        del mylist[i]
```

returns an IndexError (list assignment out of range), however,

```
for i in range(1, len(mylist), 3):
        mylist[i] = 'k'
```

Turns every second list member into the letter 'k'. Why is this?

FYI, what I'm trying to do right now is put every nucleotide into a list, and then group them by three's, then delete the two following list members after incorporating them into the first one, then moving on to the next codon.

For example:
['A', 'U', 'G'] -> [['AUG'], 'U', 'G'] -> ['AUG'], ['GCC' (the next codon)], etc...

Comment: You can't delete items from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Well, you can't delete items from a list iterating over it forwards.  You can if you go backwards.

Comment: Right. Makes sense. I guess I just don't know any other way to do what I want to do in this situation. EDIT: whoa, okay, just tried reversing the start and stop parameters for range and it is true, you can delete items from a list going backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy `bb` to `mylist` and then try to modify `mylist` in place. Just copy from `bb` to `mylist`:

```
bb = 'AUGGCCAUGGCGCCCAGAACUGAGAUCAAUAGUACCCGUAUUAACGGGUGA'
mylist = []
for i in range(0, len(bb), 3):
    mylist.append(bb[i:i+3])
print mylist
```

Output:

['AUG', 'GCC', 'AUG', 'GCG', 'CCC', 'AGA', 'ACU', 'GAG', 'AUC', 'AAU', 'AGU', 'ACC', 'CGU', 'AUU', 'AAC', 'GGG', 'UGA']

Comment: You make it seem so easy.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete an item from the list, it now has fewer items.  Consequently, the list at the position of its length - 1 no longer exists.  Lets say you have a list of length 4.  Once you try to access the list at position 2, you have already deleted 2 items, and the list has only 2 items left.  Now the list doesn't have anything at position 2.  Instead, just `del mylist[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a list of length `3`:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3']
```

No we iterate over it using `range(len(l))`:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print('i =', i)
    print('l[i] =', l[i])
    del l[i]
```

This is the result:

```
i = 0
l[i] = 1
i = 1
l[i] = 3
i = 2
------------------------------------
IndexError
<ipython-input-6-ab3e74355e73> in <m
      1 for i in range(len(l)):
      2     print('i =', i)
----> 3     print('l[i] =', l[i])
      4     del l[i]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

So in the first iteration, you delete the first element which is `'1'`,
this leaves the list as `['2', '3']`

Then we delete the seconds element of the list, which is `'3'` now and the list becomes `['2', ]`.

In the thirds iteration, `i = 2` but the list has only one element, so we get the index error.

The solution will be to do it in reverse:

```
for i in reversed(range(1, len(mylist), 3)):
        del mylist[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

`mylist` changes when you delete item from it - it contains lesser items while you are still using the indexes generated based on its original length.

For example,

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Your code suppose to remove 'B' and 'E' (number 1 and 4) from the list,

```
for i in range(1, len(mylist), 3):
    del mylist[i]
```

However after the first pass 'B' was removed, the list became ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']. At this time there are only 4 items in this list, and number 4 item does not exist any more.

What you want to do is to get a list which contains #0, #3, #6, ... items from the original list. You can simply use list slice like this:

```
print mylist[0::3]
```